# Pip freeze doesnt list all required packages

Tags: python, pip

After trying to create requirements file with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from my virtual enviroment not all of the required imports get listed. Am I doing something wrong or is there other way to list them all?

Comment: `pip freeze` gets all the packages you have installed, do you perhaps have some relative import that you didnt "install"? also, are you using anaconda?

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment before running the `pip freeze` command.

Comment: I did activate virtual enviroment and im not using anaconda. I dont have relative imports, literally just "flask_sqlalchemy, flask_migrate, flask_login, flask_bootstrap, flask". When I create the file it is completely empty

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem was that pycharm creates virtual enviroment already and I was creating new one on top of that